# Why \dt isn't showing the table? (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, heroku, psql

tried a lot, but it seems impossible now to list down the table
seeking for help badly

below is cmnds followed by the issue

```
logicsoft-internship::DATABASE=> \dn
       List of schemas
    Name    |     Owner
------------+----------------
 heroku_ext | u8q98eik4pd35o
 public     | grmgsmxgscmlmc
(2 rows)


logicsoft-internship::DATABASE=> \dt
Did not find any relations.
logicsoft-internship::DATABASE=> \dt dauokokqc98tl4
Did not find any relation named "dauokokqc98tl4".
logicsoft-internship::DATABASE=> \dt dauokokqc98tl4.public
Did not find any relation named "dauokokqc98tl4.public"
```

Comment: `\dt heroku_ext.*` or `\dt public.*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) `\dn` shows a list of schemas (=namespace).

To show the tables in a specific schema (namespace), you need to provide a wildcard with the **schema name** - you used the owner which is something completely different.

```
\dt heroku_ext.*
\dt public.*
```